# Select option using Excel Automation with Internet explorer

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I have been trying for days. I can update the value of text boxes and click on option buttons however I am unable to select the option from a drop down list

To select the drop down option I have tried:

```
 myHTMLFrame2.all.Item("QSGAA5V0GAFRWAOL34D8OK78W2ZUJO").Focus
    myHTMLFrame2.all.Item("QSGAA5V0GAFRWAOL34D8OK78W2ZUJO").selectedIndex = 1
    myHTMLFrame2.all.Item("QSGAA5V0GAFRWAOL34D8OK78W2ZUJO").FireEvent "onchange"
```

Nothing happens with the above

```
Dim myHTMLFrame2 As HTMLDocument
    Set myHTMLFrame2 = HTMLDoc.frames(3).document
    Dim elem As Object

    Set elem = myHTMLFrame2.document.getElementById("QSGAA5V0GAFRWAOL34D8OK78W2ZUJO")
(results in "object not supported error")
    elem.Focus
    elem.selectedIndex = 2
```

This is the HTML Code:

```
<div id="QSGAA5V0GAFRWAOL34D8OK78W2ZUJO-answer-body">
                    <div class="select_holder select_jquery">
                        <select id="QSGAA5V0GAFRWAOL34D8OK78W2ZUJO" overwrite="1" level="0"
                            val="$escapeTool.html($!{answerValue})" required="true" questionid="QSGAA5V0GAFRWAOL34D8OK78W2ZUJO" totalorder="0" questiondefid="QDGAA5V0GAFRWAOL34D8OK78W2ZUJP"
                            responsetype="STATIC_MENU" autocomplete="off"
                            aria-activedescendant="" aria-labelledby="QSGAA5V0GAFRWAOL34D8OK78W2ZUJO-label" tabindex="0">
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <option value="New User(s)" ps="0" aria-selected="false">New User(s)</option>
                            <option value="Modify User Details or Applications" ps="1" aria-selected="false">Modify User Details or Applications</option>
                            <option value="Add/Modify User By Attachment" ps="2" aria-selected="false">Add/Modify User By Attachment</option>
                            <option value="clear">(clear)</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: I've had a similar issue, and it turn out to be a piece of javascript handling that drop down selection. Calling the javascript was the solution for me, maybe it points you in the right direction? Here is the shortened code I've used: `IE.Navigate "javascript:NewItem('\....\u002520Validation\u002520Reports\u002fForms\u002fUpload.aspx?....\u002520Validation\u002520Reports\u0026Type=1')"`

Comment: is the url public?

Comment: @ DarXyde: Thank you for the comments. Anything that led you to the javascript, was there anything in the tag information or maybe the header?

Comment: @QHarr: Thank you no the url is not public it is hosted intranet and is part of the Remedy system

Comment: I'm gonna post something to try in a sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Qharr & @Deepak -- Thank You

I examined the element and turns out the code creates an "input" element at run time. In order to execute the event I am using send keys. Not very elegant but it works.

```
myHTMLFrame2.all.Item("QSGAA5V0GAFRWAOL34D8OK78W2ZUJO_input").Focus
myHTMLFrame2.all.Item("QSGAA5V0GAFRWAOL34D8OK78W2ZUJO_input").Value = "New User(s)"
myHTMLFrame2.all.Item("QSGAA5V0GAFRWAOL34D8OK78W2ZUJO_input").Click
Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}"
Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}"
Application.SendKeys "~"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try attaching an event to the select element. I have targeted using tag and attribute in case id is dynamic. If id static then use that. If it is inside the iframe then add the appropriate syntax in front to access.

```
Dim dropDown As Object, onChange As Object
Set dropDown = ie.document.querySelector("select[overwrite='1']")
Set onChange = ie.document.createEvent("htmlevents")
onChange.initEvent "change", True, False
ie.document.querySelector("[value='New User(s)']").Selected = True
links.dispatchEvent onChange
```

Comment: Thank you I was hopeful this would work as this code is new approach. unfortunately it did not   Dim myHTMLFrame2 As HTMLDocument
    Set myHTMLFrame2 = HTMLDoc.frames(3).document
    Dim dropdown As Object, onChange As Object
    Set dropdown = myHTMLFrame2.querySelector("select[overwrite='1']")
    Set onChange = myHTMLFrame2.createEvent("htmlevents")
    onChange.initEvent "change", True, False
    myHTMLFrame2.document.querySelector("[value='New User(s)']").Selected = True
    Links.dispatchEvent onChange (this resulted in an object not supported)

Comment: please post the exact error message and the line it occurs on

Comment: Dim dropdown As Object, onChange As Object  
 Set dropdown = myHTMLFrame2.querySelector("select[overwrite='1']")  
 Set onChange = myHTMLFrame2.document.createEvent("htmlevents")  
'document results in "object doesn't support this property or method" removed document then no error  
 onChange.initEvent "change", True, False  
 myHTMLFrame2.querySelector("[value='New User(s)']").Selected = True  
 Links.dispatchEvent onChange  
'error "object required" so I changed to  
myHTMLFrame2.Links.dispatchEvent onChange  
'Above line error "object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: This line myHTMLFrame2.querySelector("[value='New User(s)']").Selected = True  is producing the error?

Comment: Set onChange = myHTMLFrame2.document.createEvent("htmlevents")    
'document results in error "object doesn't support this property or method" removed document then no error  
Set onChange = myHTMLFrame2.createEvent("htmlevents")  Links.dispatchEvent onChange  
'error "object required" so I changed to  
myHTMLFrame2.Links.dispatchEvent onChange  
'Above line error "object doesn't support this property or method"

Answer (score 0):

Try to make test with code below may help to solve the issue.

Code:

```
     Sub demo()

            Dim URL As String
            Dim IE As Object

            Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

            IE.Visible = True

            URL = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\107.html"

            IE.Navigate URL

            Do While IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do While
            Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do Until

             IE.Document.GetElementByID("QSGAA5V0GAFRWAOL34D8OK78W2ZUJO").Value = "Modify User Details or Applications"

            Set IE = Nothing  


End Sub
```

Output in IE 11:

[image]

Comment: thanks but nothing happens  myHTMLFrame2.getElementById("QSGAA5V0GAFRWAOL34D8OK78W2ZUJO").Value = "New User(s)"

Comment: I suggest you to first check that your object for HTML document is properly assigned  and it refers to the correct page. after that you can try to find the element in document.